# Ionic/Angular: Manage custom navigation History for back button

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I've `<user />`, an `angular.component` that is a user's profile page that includes 4 tabs, like this:

[image]

Using `ui-router` I show a different template depending on the selected `tab` in the `ion-tabs` (`details`/`followers`/`following`/`photos`)

**My problem is**: when I click the back button it navigates also between the child views (`home.user.details`, `home.user.followers`, ...) instead of going directly to the previous view (e.g. `home`)

The best solution I can think about is to pass the previous views's name as parameter to `home.user`, this way I get the right `prev` view but I can't see it in `<user />`'s controller

```
.state('home.user', {
  url: '/user/:id',
  abstract: false,
  cache: true,
  template: '<user></user>',
  resolve: {
    id: function($stateParams) {
      return $stateParams.id;
    },
    prev: function($ionicHistory) {
      return $ionicHistory.currentView()
    }
  }
})
.state('home.user.details', {
  url: '/details',
  templateUrl: 'template/user.details.html'
})

.state('home.user.followers', {
  url: '/followers',
  templateUrl: 'template/user.followers.html'
})

// Same for home.user.following and home.user.photos
```

- How can I pass `prev` to `<user />`?
- Is there a better way to solve my navigation problem?

**EDIT**

These are the tabs in `<user />`'s template:

```
    <ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab ui-sref="home.user.details">
      </ion-tab>
      <ion-tab ui-sref="home.user.followers">
      </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
    <ion-nav-view class="inner-view"></ion-nav-view>
```

Comment: Are you using $state.go to move between the child states?

Comment: @tpsilva I use `ui-sref`. I've updated my question :)

Comment: Looks like ui-sref-opt="{location: 'replace'}" is meant for that, but theres an [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1007) that is currently unsolved.

Comment: Yeah, that's interesting and I've tried using something similar without success, it works well only the first time. Any idea on how I could pass the prev view to my user directive?